# Exponential-like power series with Fibonnaci coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, matrices, group-theory

**Background**

I am considering a problem (for fun, not homework!) of the exponential of a certain matrix,

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & a & b\\ 0 & 0 & c & 0\\ a & -c & 0 & 0\\b & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

This has relevance as a certain generator of transformations in SO(3,1), for example. By computing powers of the matrix, I found that only four matrices are involved in its powers: $A$ itself, these two:
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix} a^2+b^2 & -ac& 0&0\\ac&-c^2&0&0\\0&0&a^2-c^2&ab\\0&0&ab&b^2\end{bmatrix},\quad \tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & c\\ 0 & 0 &-b&a\\0&b&0&0\\c&-a&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and the identity matrix. Defining scalars $\alpha = a^2+b^2-c^2$ and $\beta = bc$, the powers of $A$ are:

$
A^0 = I\\
A^1 = A\\
A^2 = P\\
A^3 = \alpha A + \beta\tilde{A}\\
A^4 = \alpha P + \beta^2I\\
A^5 = (\alpha^2+\beta^2)A + \alpha\beta\widetilde{A}\\
\quad\quad\cdots
$

because $A\tilde{A} = \beta I$. I have been able to find series solutions for $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta = 0$ separately (and of course $\alpha=\beta=0$), because there is a clear pattern in the series coefficients for $\exp(A)$. These correspond to certain special cases in the vectors describing the transformation (here, $\vec{A}=(0,a,b)$ and $\vec{B}=(0,0,c)$, so the cases correspond to $\alpha=|A|^2-|B|^2=0$ and $\beta=\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=0$ respectively).

My question is about a third interesting special case, where $\alpha=\beta\neq 0$. In this case, the pattern in the matrix products generates a Fibonnaci sequence, so that the exponential series may be grouped into four series,

\begin{equation}
\exp(A) = A\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\text{Fib}_{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\alpha^k + \text{ other matrices}
\end{equation}

with the other series also containing similar sequences.

**My question is**, is anyone was familiar with the function:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\text{Fib}_{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}
\end{equation}

I know that it has an infinite radius of convergence by ratio test. Does it relate to any special functions?

**Edit**

I have mainly resolved this thanks to Professor Vector's help! The odd powers of A can be written

\begin{equation}
A^{2n+1} = c_{n+1}A + d_{n+1}\tilde{A}
\end{equation}

where the coefficients satisfy the recurrence relations

\begin{equation}
c_n = \alpha c_{n-1} + \beta^2 c_{n-2},\quad c_0 = 0, c_1 = 1
\end{equation}

and $d_n = \beta c_{n-1}$. This is a second-order linear recurrence relation and has closed-form solutions (omitted for brevity). In the special case $\alpha = \beta$, then the coefficients are $c_n = F_n\alpha^{n-1}$. In the matrix exponential, one finds that function as the coefficient of $A$,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{F_{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\alpha^k = \frac{\sinh(\sqrt{\phi\alpha}) - \sin(\sqrt{\alpha/\phi})}{\sqrt{5}\alpha}
\end{equation}

where $\phi$ is the Golden ratio, using Binet's formula for $F_n$, as Professor Vector pointed out! Interesting to see $\phi$ show up here. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: If you use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html, you'll recognize the connection with Taylor series for $\sin$ and $\sinh$.

Comment: That is so awesome. Thank you!